# How can I authenticate with the machine account during SPNego authentication?

Tags: httpclient, iis-7.5, pinvoke, ntlm, spnego

My goal is to create a HTTPS REST service that (in concept) allows a machine account to authenticate using the less- than documented machine$ account.

I have a REST endpoint for an AD connected intranet application. Right now IIS simply echoes the thread CurrentPrincipal when I navigate using Internet Explorer.

Now I'm using the HTTPClient , using default authentication, running a my username, and that also works.

My new goal is to send the AD Connected machineAccount (that ends in the dollar sign $) so that IIS responds with the kerberos name Domain\TestServer$

I attempted creating a Windows Desktop service, running as NetworkService or LocalSystem, and I'm not clear if HttpClientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials is sufficient for running in this (unusual) context or if a different approach is needed to authenticate using the machine account.

Is a PInvoke needed? Is there anything in logonuser32 that needs to be done?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/1605278

Comment: Running as `SYSTEM` or `NETWORK SERVICE` is sufficient.

Comment: Hi @Steve, I am getting a socket exception on the client when I attempt to do this using HTTPCLIENT and Default Credentials as the HttpClientHandler but that doesn't work either. I'm now trying to decrypt the machine  password in $machine.acc in the registry so I can create a network credential from it.

Comment: Running in system wasn't enough

Comment: This should work by design without any heavy lifting. Please do not extract the $machine.acc creds. How are you launching the process as `SYSTEM`? You may not be getting the right privileges.

Comment: I'm running as an interactive service account, and am now able to get it working with WebRequest (not HTTPClient). Part of my other issue was configuring IIS8 to not run in kernel mode, and added the kerberos module. Thanks for all your help @Steve, will delete code regarding $machine.acc